# How can formal insulators "conduct" electric and magnetic fields?

Tags: electric-field

Is there an explanation regarding the ability of an insulator between capacitor's plates to be permeable to an electric field?
The terms "valence band" and "conduction band" the large distance between which defines an insulator deal with electron transfer. Whereas an insulator between capacitor's plates is still supposed to be permeable to an electric field.

By the same token, magnets (e.g. N45) attract each other with little loss in force or velocity even through such formal insulators as household plastic or rubber. Can it be assumed that a static electric field can be established with little loss of electrical energy through a plastic? (as generated between 2 uninsulated conductors connected to a voltage source and separated by min. 1.5-2 cm (or more) of air and a plastic plate)

Comment: Depends what level of explanation you are looking for. The most fundamental one (that I am aware of) lies in a quantum field theory. In its terms the electromagnetic field is a quantum operator creating/annihilating its quanta - the photons. The parameters of this operators - that is just some constant coefficients - depend on the properties of the medium - that is the insulator material and how its particles interact with the photons.

Comment: such insulators block the movement of electrons.  they do not "block" the charge.  The only way to "block" a charge (ie electric field) is with an opposite charge.

Comment: @Abel They do block the transfer of charge

Comment: Maybe some different wording will help: transfer and electric field are two different things.  Let's call the plates of the capacitor A and C.  Negative charges accumulated at A can still push on electrons at C much like you can push on a flexible membrane to push what's on the other side without going through the membrane itself.  Membrane failed to block force although it did block your hand.

Comment: @Abel I think it is important to recognize is that **charge** and **electric field** are two quite different things.

Comment: On the basis of this quantum field framework an insulator should reduce the external electromagnetic field, while at least the magnets mutually attract through plastic as if there were no plastic inbetween.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson I think we mean the same thing.  what you call a charge, I call a charged mass.  Reason why I don't want to say block charge is that by repelling electrons, one can cause the other entity to become charged on another surface (capacitors in series).  And this semantics is why the poster is confused in the first place.

Comment: I think you are starting to use sloppy language. You started out asking about insulators being "permeable" to electric fields, then moved to "little loss of electrical energy", but now you use the stronger "should reduce the...field". You start with a qualitative argument but when that doesn't work you try to sneak in some quantitative adjectives.

Comment: i agree on that point.  my language is sloppy.  But so is the "standard."  This question is itself evidence of that. May we understand reality even if we can't communicate it.

Comment: @Abel OK, so a charge is a "charged mass". It is still a completely different beast than an "electric field". And "become charged" is just poor language, it conflates the notions of charge and fields. A capacitor doesn't require the movement of charge, or charged mass, through the insulator in order for an electric field to be established.

Comment: @Abel What is this "standard" and why is it in quotes?

Comment: May YOU understand reality even if I can't communicate it.

Comment: For the current purpose of the question I'd stick to "little loss of electrical energy". For my installation I may need to ensure that there will be no gross energy loss of static electric or magnetic field through regular insulators like plastic, wood, rubber.

Comment: There probably should be some diagrams showing how capacitor's function depends on various types of insulators between the plates

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Charge and electric field are sort of different entities. But every charge has its own intrinsic electric field related to it (this is why basically it is a charge), as mentioned in general introductory materials on electronics. So an insulator does not conduct charges while still being able to normally conduct their electric fields?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your confusion comes from some vocabulary semantics.  On one hand I've seen the term "current" used to describe the flow of "charge."  On the other hand, while the movement of "charge" is necessary, the movement need not be continuous in one direction (alternating current).

It helps to think of what might be happening to the electrons themselves.  In a capacitor they accumulate on one of the faces.  Their electric field (which does not get blocked) in turn forces the electrons on the other face to move away.  Since an electron is an electron, it didn't matter to the circuit that it was a different electron.  The amount of electrons you can move in this way is limited by the amount of force all those electrons close together.

Alternating current is a way to move energy even within this limitation pushing and pulling electrons.  While a capacitor will block DC current across it once it becomes charged, it will not outright block AC.

The electrical field drops off quite rapidly (distance squared) as you get far away from your charged particle and it takes voltage to force electrons together.  In other words, it is possible to conduct electricity through rubber if the voltage is sufficiently high or the rubber sufficiently thin.

If transmission is the purpose though, you will likely find that using magnetic fields is more suitable since high voltage tends to be more difficult to contain (and hence more dangerous - your purpose is to conduct it through an insulator so you'll need an even better insulator to contain it) than a strong magnetic field.

Comment: The electrical field drops by distance squared for monopolar coulomb charges (used in Coulomb's research) with their intrinsic electric field. Does the electrical field established by an extrinsic bipolar voltage source like the one in a capacitor also drops in the same way?

Comment: The purpose is to conduct the electric field rather than current through plastic with little loss of energy.

Comment: In some ways yes: the fundamentals are the same and in theory if you made a model that accounted for all the charges everywhere at all times, and superimposed anything else affecting the system, you'd get results. In other ways no: accounting for all the protons and electrons everywhere is impossible.  Use it as an approximation at best, and don't forget to account for the full circuit loop of your power transmission device.  It should be good enough to tell you something about what happens when you try to transmit a + and - next to each other (spoiler: distances are not practical).

Comment: I recommend you look into "Wireless power transfer" Wikipedia should have a good article.  There's also some recent work with harvesting energy from 5G out there.  My take on it so far is that we won't be replacing power lines or house wiring with wireless due to inefficiency and danger.